# GTK+, GLADE, PYTHON 3.6 Windows

Tags: python-3.x, gtk, glade

I am an Electrical engineer. I am completely new for programming and coding..

Actually i am working as estimation engineer, where i am doing the same estimation again and again with excel.

As same in design stage also i am doing the same again and again.

I thought i will create a application which will automatically do the estimation based on my input. and the same time at the time of design stage it will input from my estimation sheet it will generate the drawing automatically.

(i am doing estimation in excel, preparing drawing in auto cad)

from google, i found the following..

To write a program I need to know a language. so i selected python version 3.6.1

To create a stand alone or micro soft windows installer i selected cx freeze which is converting my code to .exe filex

To create a user interface i selected glade.

But i dont know how to install gtk builder to link pythin code and glade files.

Hopefully you got the point what i am looking..

I am using windiws 10 with 64 bit version

Advance thanks for all

Answer (score 0):

All the information you need on how to install GTK+ and Glade on Windows is on the [GTK+ Website](https://www.gtk.org/download/windows.php).

However, If you're a total beginner, then I suggest you start small, as the kind of work you're describing seems a lot of work for someone who has never written a single line of code.

Comment: Hai, Libeforce.. Thanks for the reply. As you said, i have never written a single line of code. But from the past six month i am learning python.                                                   i wrote some simple code with print, if, while, break etc and convertedto .msi by Cx freeze. From glade i create my window. when i want to load the glade file in python code, i need to install gtk. i am trying to install from Gtk+ website. its giving link with msys2. i dont know how the

Comment: Yes, the prefered way to install GTK+ for development on Windows is through the MSYS2 project.

Comment: Fine. But can you please guide me how to install from MSYS2.. I tried and failed. Its a great help if show me a step by step procedure and one example fwith python script

Comment: I wrote a step-by-step guide of all actions one need to do to setup a GTK+ development environement... And the result is what currently is on the https://www.gtk.org/download/windows.php webpage (and that AFAIK works). I can't guide you if I don't know what you do. So please precisely describe what you have done, and at which step you're blocked, and the associated error message.

Comment: Thanks.. i got it...if any thing required i will comment again.. if you don't mind can i your what's up contact no..

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @liberforce, install GTK+ and Glade on Windows from their [GTK+ Website](https://www.gtk.org/download/windows.php). This way you will have an environment (MINGW64) **inside** which you can practice.

Install python from their [download site](https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/).

Check also [these instructions](https://pygobject.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html#windows-getting-started) for how to use it.
The key points (at least for me) are:

- **Copy** the hello.py script you created to `C:\msys64\home\<username>`
- **In the mingw32 terminal** execute `python3 hello.py` - a window should appear.

After that, if you want to make an executable, follow [these instructions](https://blogs.gnome.org/nacho/2014/08/01/how-to-build-your-gtk-application-on-windows/). Try their example for gedit to get some ideas on how to create and how PKGBUILD works (a.k.a. follow the [instructions for gedit](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gedit/tree/master/win32) to see what's happening).